# Python - basic issue with if statement?

Tags: python

why do I keep getting "r" in results instead of "0" when I type r or R in input?

```
from random import randint

# Input
print("Rock: R   Paper: P   Scissors: S")
x = input("Please pick your choice: ")
y = randint(0,2)

if x.lower() == "r":
    x == 0;


print("value entered ", x, "value generated ", y)
```

Comment: x == 0; is a boolean evaluating to true, you want x = 0

Comment: What is your python version? 3x or 2x?

Answer (score 1):

`x == 0;` is a boolean evaluating to `False` in your case. It tests if the value of x is equal to 0.

What you want is `x = 0`;

Comment: I'm guessing it'd be false if `x` is `'r'`, not that it matters :)

Comment: I think OP knows about his statement `if x.lower() == "r"` but not about `x == 0;` meaning

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

- First, you want `x = 0` (assignment), not `x == 0` (comparison).
- Second, your test (`if x.lower() == "r":`) is always going to be false, because your input has a trailing newline (that is, `x` will usually be something like `"r\n"`. You want `if x.strip().lower() == "r":` instead.

Comment: Thats why `raw_input` is better.

Comment: No, ``raw_input`` is better because input runs ``eval`` on the user-supplied input and is a huge security risk (try typing ``__import__('os').system('rm -rf ~')`` at an input prompt, for example). ``raw_input`` will give you the trailing newline just the same.

However, Python 3's ``input`` is Python 2's ``raw_input``, renamed (Python 2's ``input`` was removed in Python 3).

Comment: You're assuming he/she's using python 2.x

Comment: in python 2.x `raw_input` doesn't give the trailing `\n`. See the `help(raw_input)`. It says `Read a string from standard input.  The trailing newline is stripped.`